# How do I iterate a QStringList in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qstringlist

When selecting multiple files using the `getOpenFileNames` command in **PyQt5**, the list it returns is in the form of a `QStringList`. However, I have found no viable method to iterate this list and pick out each file name individually.

I have scoured every square inch of the internet looking for a solution, and I'm hard pressed to believe that `QStringList` does not allow for iteration.

Is there a way to iterate each string in a `QStringList`?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful or related [Converting a QStringList (PyQt) into a normal python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577175/converting-a-qstringlist-pyqt-into-a-normal-python-list)

Comment: I have seen that and it did not solve my issue.

Comment: Can you post complete code to create a `QStringList`? It's not in `PyQt5.Qt` ...

Comment: getOpenFileNames returns a QStringList, it is indeed a part of PyQt5 framework. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html

Comment: @IAmTheKDENoob The only way that `getOpenFileNames` could return a `QStringList` is if you were using pyqt4 with python2. For pyqt5 with either python2 or python3, the `QStringList` and `QString` classes *are no longer directly supported at all* - so they will always be automatically converted to their python equivalents (i.e. `list` and `str`, respectively). If you are seeing different behaviour, there is either something else wrong with your code, or you are using an old/buggy version of pyqt. (PS: you do realise that `getOpenFileNames` returns a two-tuple of a list and a string, right?)

Comment: @IAmTheKDENoob Sanity check. Start a new python interactive session, and input the following statements: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog; app = QApplication(['']); print(repr(QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()))`. What output do you get? Here's what I get, using python 3.7.2 and pyqt 5.11.3: `(['/tmp/foo.py', '/tmp/bar.py'], 'All Files (*)')`. As you can see, there's no `QStringList`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for i in range(len(somelist)):
    print(somelist[i])
```

Comment: Doesn't work for QStringList. 

"TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"

Comment: @IAmTheKDENoob Can you try now?

Comment: If it was that simple I would have been done last week. But FileDialog.getOpenFileNames only returns one large block when selecting multiple files. Normal iterators won't work. Neither will built-in python methods. QStringList is in its own class.

Comment: According to http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstringlist.html, `QStringList` implements both `__len__` and `__getitem__`. Can you clarify exactly what's wrong?

Comment: Iterating through each file selected using the method getOpenFileNames is impossible using either of those commands. Have you tried it? Selecting multiple files using getOpenFileNames returns one large QString block inside a QStringList. Length does not and will not work for this method as it will always return 1. The QString block of file names and the File Filter information.

Comment: @IAmTheKDENoob This is information you need to put in your question. Give your input list, and also show your desired output.

Comment: The information is already readily available in my original question. I have stated previously the usage of getOpenFileNames. I don't see the confusion unless you are not familiar with the Qt framework.

Comment: @IAmTheKDENoob I have only done stuff with Qt in C++, and have never encountered anything of the sorts. Still, you should include some code and sample input/output in your question. Please show what you have tried, and how it hasn't worked.